# elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.5.0 BulkRequest Not working anymore

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've updated elasticsearch from 6.4.2 to 6.5.0 and the BulkRequest using the rest high level client api is not working anymore:

```
final BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
myarray().forEach(elem -> {
  try {
    final XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    builder.startObject();
    {
      builder.timeField("@timestamp", elem.getTimestamp());
      builder.field("metric", elem.getMetric().getName());
      builder.field("resource", elem.getResource().getName());
      builder.field("value", elem.getValue());
      builder.field("windowId", elem.getWindowId());
    }
    builder.endObject();
    System.out.println(builder.prettyPrint());
    final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("myindex-2018.11.20", "mytype");
    indexRequest.source(builder);
    request.add(indexRequest);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error forward", e);
  }
});
BulkResponse response = client.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

If I perform a single IndexRequest it works fine:

```
final XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
builder.startObject();
{
  builder.timeField("@timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
  builder.field("metric", "test");
  builder.field("resource", "test");
  builder.field("value", "-1");
  builder.field("windowId", "test");
}
builder.endObject();
final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("myindex-2018.11.20", "mytype");
indexRequest.source(builder);
final IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Both queries where running well with the version 6.4.2, now with the version 6.5.0 only the second one is working.

I don't receive any errors

Comment: Can you check in the ES logs if you can spot any errors in the logs?

Comment: No errors (docker-compose logs -f elasticsearch, I deployed elk using docker-compose)

Comment: Can you enable `TRACE` level logging for the `tracer` and `org.elasticsearch.client` packages? i.e. `org.elasticsearch.client:TRACE`and `tracer:TRACE`